# Delayed, Resettable Function Delays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am working on a TODO app in React and am trying to build in functionality that will delay the removal of a checked item by X seconds, and if the box is unchecked within that time it will not get deleted.

The main issue I am running into is when a user checks, unchecks and rechecks all within that same X seconds. The desired functionality is that if you were to check, the timer starts, uncheck and the timer resets, check again new timer starts. Right now the timer keeps going, so if X = 5, then if you check, uncheck and recheck all within 5 seconds the item gets deleted too soon.

```
  handleToggle = value => () => {
    const { checked } = this.state;
    const currentIndex = checked.indexOf(value);
    const newChecked = [...checked];

    if (currentIndex === -1) {
      newChecked.push(value);
    } else {
      newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1);
    }

    this.setState({
      checked: newChecked
    });

    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(
        () =>
          resolve(
            this.state.checked.includes(value) ? Store.delete(value.id) : false
          ),
        3000
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <List>
          {Store.get().map(item => (
            <ListItem
              key={item.id}
              role={undefined}
              dense
              button
              className={classes.listItem}
            >
              <Checkbox
                onClick={this.handleToggle(item)}
                checked={this.state.checked.indexOf(item) !== -1}
                tabIndex={-1}
                disableRipple
              />
              <TextField
                id={item.id}
                className={classes.textField}
                value={item.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange(item)}
                margin="normal"
              />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a key into the state when checking. Use this key in the function inside setTimeout and only delete if the key is unchanged between the check and timeout.

The key needs to be something that won't be the same at different times, so you could use an incrementing number or something simple like the current unix time `new Date().valueOf()`

If an item is checked twice, the second check will overwrite the key, thus making the timed deletion of the first check fail when comparing keys.

```
handleToggle = value => () => {
  const { checked, keys } = this.state;
  const currentIndex = checked.indexOf(value);
  const newChecked = [...checked];
  const newKeys = [...keys];
  const key = new Date().valueOf();

  if (currentIndex === -1) {
    newChecked.push(value);
    newKeys[value] = key;
  } ...

  this.setState({
    checked: newChecked,
    keys: newKeys
  });

  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(
      () =>
        resolve(
          (this.state.checked.includes(value) && this.state.keys[value] === key) ? Store.delete(value.id) : false
        ),
      3000
    );
  });
};
```

Don't forget to initialize `this.state.keys` with an empty object.